# update of dataset doesn't work? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset

I've a WPF situation with one page that has a datagrid with clients, and another page with field to fill in a new client.

I want the "new-client-page" to search the highest clientID en increment that with 1 for the new client, this sounds very simple, but I've a problem with it.

In the table adapter of the table, I added a new query: `SELECT MAX(clientID) FROM clients`

I execute the query with:

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.klantenTableAdapter tableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.klantenTableAdapter();
DataSet1 datasetvar = new DataSet1();
int returnValue = (int)tableAdapter.GetMaxKlantnr();
```

This works fine once. I get the highest value in `returnValue`, but if I go for the second time to the "new-client-page", the clientID is still the same..

I tried to update the dataset with `tableAdapter.Update(datasetvar);` but that doesnt make sense.. :(

Comment: Why are you choosing IDs on the client? Why not let the database assign the ID?

Comment: How can I do that? Auto increment or something?

Answer (score 1):

Lars what database are you using? Set the ID column as identity and it will be auto generated by the db, your solution would not support any concurrency anyway and it's not the way to go to read the max id and add 1 to it...

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5. I can't find there "identity". Also another question related to this: what do I have to fill in, in my INSERT query? Now I use INSERT INTO clients VALUES (clientID, name, city.... etc);

Comment: once the field is marked as identity you don't have to specify the clientid fieldname and value anymore in your insert. Not sure but I would imagine SQL Compact _HAS_ support for identities...

Comment: Allright i found out, how to do. But this is not the solution for me. A has to do it how I said in my question, because I want to make a program with a backup system. So once my PC crashes or whatever, with one click I can put in the internet data back into my local DB. The identity column dont allow changes..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it when you add a new row. It is then executed as an INSERT by the adapter. Adapters commit only changes.

The code would look almost like:

```
var newRow = ClientTable.NewRow();

newRow["ClientID"] = GetNewID();
...set other fields...

ClientTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

Adapter.Update(ClientTable);
```